# Data fetched from API with useQuery GraphQL hook is passed to children but not rendering in the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, graphql

I am not sure why the data of `searchBarAccordion.jsx` is not being rendered in the DOM although its data is showing up in the console.

The files in question are `searchBar.jsx` and `searchBarAccordion.jsx`in
[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jbdkdm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/searchBar.jsx)

Could you please help?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I omitted the `return` statement in the `map` function in `searchBarAccordion.jsx`...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGlkr.png)